# Como resolver o problema de CordinatorLayout do Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou começando a estudar desenvolvimento mobile android e peguei vários problemas com o Android Studio 3.1.3.

E um deles que eu não estou conseguindo corrigir é o problema de renderização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei diversos métodos, inclusive alguns que estão aqui no site e não consegui resolver o problema ou não fiz direito, não sei como criar uma dependência ou adicionar uma.

Quando o app carrega ele mostra o seguinte:

[image: ddd]

Eu não sei como corrigir isso.

Comment: Isso é um bug da lib e vai ser corrigido na proxima release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu mesmo consegui resolver o problema.
Encontrei vários passos aqui no site pra poder resolver o problema e nenhum deles resolveram.
Então fuçando no AS eu vi que a api 28 estava pré-instalada nele, e é como se fosse uma api que ainda não tinha sido concluída.
Então instalei juntamente a api 28 a api 27.
Reiniciei o cache do AS e ele funcionou perfeitamente.